# How to use 'There being"?

Tags: usage

I have rarely heard this phrase, is it not comman phrase ? How to use the phrase 'There being' ? I've tried to use it in the following sentences:

1. > There being an exam tomorrow, I'm unable to go to market.
2. > There being a mysterious murder of the king, the kingdom is in a deep silence.
3. > There being a dispute over a topic of environment, the country is to make an effective law for its sustainable development.

Could you please tell me that is it a correct way to use 'There being' ?

Or There is a different usage of it ?

I would appreciate your responses. Thank you

Comment: All three are correct to me, albeit strange-sounding. *There being* pretty much translates to *Since there is*.

Comment: *There being* basically means something like "because there is".  #1 and #3 sound good to me, because *there is an exam tomorrow* and *there is a dispute*, but #2 sounds wrong to me, because there isn't a murder right now, the murder is something that already happened.  I would phrase it as "There having been a mysterious murder", because *there has been a murder*, not *there is a murder*.

Comment: Could you please try to answer me ?

Comment: I haven't been answered why ?

Answer (score 1):

1 and 3 are correct but archaic. Today we would say, "Because there is".

2 should be "There having been", but that too is archaic. Today we would say, "Because there had been."